# Show that function is Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space $V$ with a basis $B = \{e^t, e^{5t}, te^t\}$. How would I should that a function $\phi(f) = f'$ is an endomorphism? Assume that linearity is already proven.

I know that an endomorphism is a linear function that maps elements to the same space they "came from". One guess would be to check whether the image of the function is spanned by the same basis that the original space V is spanned by (?). Or could I "check" its representation matrix and somehow see if it is an endomorphism? The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism) does not really help me at all. Any help and intuition would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you assume the linearity, it suffices to prove that the derivatives of the given maps can be span by the initial maps. This is quite immediate!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thank you very much for your reply! So, if I understand correctly, I can put a "generic" input through the function and check if it can still be expressed by the basis vectors of the initial vector space the input came from.

Comment: That is exactly what should be done!

Answer (score 1):

First, for any $f\in V$, write $f\left(t\right)=a_1e^t+a_2 e^{5t}+a_3 te^t$. Then $f'\left(t\right)=\left(a_1+a_3\right)e^t+5a_2 e^{5t}+a_3 te^t\in V$. Hence $\phi$ maps elements of $V$ into $V$ itself.

Second, for any $f_1,f_2\in V$, since $\phi\left(f_1+f_2\right)=\left(f_1+f_2\right)'=f_1'+f_2'=\phi\left(f_1\right)+\phi\left(f_2\right)$, and for any $c\in\mathbb{C}$, $\phi\left(cf_1\right)=\left(cf_1\right)'=cf_1'=c\phi\left(f_1\right)$, $\phi$ is a homomorphism and hence is an endomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the concept now that I see it :)